# Norm preserving extensions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory

### The Problem

> Construct a bounded linear functional on some $L^{1}(\mu)$  which has two ( hence infinitely many) distinct norm preserving extensions.

### Questions

How would you go about finding examples?

There are just so many possible permutations it's hard to figure out what to choose. A solution to this would require knowing:

1. Measure space - (X,$\mu$, $\Sigma$)
2. Subspace of $L^{1}(\mu)$ - $M$
3. Bounded Linear functional - $u: M\to \mathbb{C}$
4. Distinct Bounded Norm Preserving Linear extensions- $U_1, U_2: L^{1}(\mu)\to \mathbb{C}$

But each of these is very nontrivial to guess. I assume that you should guess each one and see what turns out. But all my examples went nowhere.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

( Also the extension is unique if $L^{1}(\mu)$ is replaced with a Hilbert space)

### Note

$||u||=\sup\{| u(f)| :  ||f||\leq 1, f\in M\}$

$||U_i||=\sup\{| U_i(f)| :  ||f||\leq 1, f\in L^{1}(\mu)\}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $M = \left\{ f\in L^1([0,1]): f(x) = 0 \ \forall x\in \left[0,\frac{1}{2} \right] \right\}$.

It is clear that for $f,g \in M$ and scalar $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}$, then $f+g, \alpha f \in L^1([0,1])$
and $f(x)+g(x) = 0 = \alpha f(x) \ \forall x\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$. Hence $M$ is a subspace of $L^1([0,1])$.

We also have that $\|\chi_{(1/2, 1]}\|_1 = 1/2$, hence $\chi_{(1/2, 1]} \in L^1([0,1])$ and obviously $\chi_{(1/2, 1]} \in M$, hence $M$ is not empty.

Let $\Lambda: M \to \mathbb{C}: \Lambda f = \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = \int_{1/2}^1 f(x)\,dx$. It is easy to check that $\Lambda$ is a bounded linear functional on $M$ and moreover that $\|\Lambda\| = 1$.

For $\alpha \in (0, \frac{1}{2})$, let $\Lambda_{\alpha}: L^1([0,1]) \to \mathbb{C}: \Lambda_{\alpha} f = \int_0^1 f(x) \chi_{(\alpha,1)}(x)\,dx = \int_{\alpha}^1 f(x) \,dx$.
It is clear that $\Lambda_{\alpha}|_M = \int_{1/2}^{1} f(x)\,dx = \Lambda$, hence $\Lambda_{\alpha}$ is an extension of $\Lambda$.

Also
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \|\lambda_{\alpha}\| &= \sup \{\|\Lambda_{\alpha} f \| : f \in L^1([0,1]), \ \|f\|_1 \le 1\} \\
        &= \sup \left\{\left| \int_{\alpha}^{1} f(x)\,dx \right| : f \in L^1([0,1]), \ \|f\|_1 \le 1 \right\} \\
        &= \sup \left\{\left| \int_{\alpha}^{1} f(x)\,dx \right| \le \int_{0}^{1} |f(x)|\,dx : f \in L^1([0,1]), \ \int_{0}^{1} \left| f(x) \right| \,dx \le 1 \right\} \\
        &= 1 = \|\Lambda\| \\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Hence $\Lambda_{\alpha}$ is norm-preserving.
Then obviously for any $\beta \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ such that $\alpha \neq \beta$, we have that $\Lambda_{\alpha} \neq \Lambda_{\beta}$.
Hence $\Lambda$ is a bounded linear functional on $M$ that has infinitely many norm-preserving extensions $\Lambda_{\alpha}$ to $L^1([0,1])$.